# Pygame will not blit lists of images

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

I started building a simple window in python with pygame to iterate through a list of images and blit them.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

Window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
bg = pygame.image.load("/Users/luke.redwine/Documents/Python/PyGame/Examples/pygame lesson spaceinvaders/space.jpg")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

animateNeutral = [pygame.image.load("/Users/luke.redwine/Documents/Python/PyGame/Space Shooter Game/Plasma T Neutral %s.png"% frame)for frame in range (1,3)] 
animateFiring = [pygame.image.load("/Users/luke.redwine/Documents/Python/PyGame/Space Shooter Game/plasma T fire %s.png"% frame)for frame in range (1,7)]

running = True
while running:
    events = pygame.event.get()
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in events:             
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT or keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            pygame.quit()

    Window.blit(bg, (0,0))
    clock.tick(10)
    Window.blit(animateNeutral)
    Window.blit(animateFiring)
pygame.quit()
```

i tried to quickly make it so i could just see it animate, but it threw up this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/luke.redwine/Documents/Python/PyGame/Space Shooter Game/space rpg.py", line 22, in <module>
    Window.blit(animateNeutral)
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not list
```

Comment: Will it blit a single image? But not iterate? Because you can interate for it. It clearly states that it needs a pygame.Surface, not a list of pygame.Surface

Comment: It does not. and I understand what the error means now but I don't know another way to go through all the images in one go. I've done it before in another project and it worked. not sure what I'm doing wrong with it this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blit function requires a surface argument.

You can use the built-in [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to create a generator that will cycle through the images forever.

Here's some untested code based on your sample:

```
import itertools
import pygame
pygame.init()

Window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
bg = pygame.image.load("/Users/luke.redwine/Documents/Python/PyGame/Examples/pygame lesson spaceinvaders/space.jpg")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

animateNeutral = [pygame.image.load("/Users/luke.redwine/Documents/Python/PyGame/Space Shooter Game/Plasma T Neutral %s.png"% frame)for frame in range (1,3)] 
animateFiring = [pygame.image.load("/Users/luke.redwine/Documents/Python/PyGame/Space Shooter Game/plasma T fire %s.png"% frame)for frame in range (1,7)]

neutral_animations = itertools.cycle(animateNeutral)
firing_animations = itertools.cycle(animateFiring)

neutral_dest = (50, 50)
firing_dest = (200, 50)

running = True
while running:
    events = pygame.event.get()
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in events:             
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT or keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            pygame.quit()

    Window.blit(bg, (0,0))
    clock.tick(10)
    Window.blit(next(neutral_animations), neutral_dest)
    Window.blit(next(firing_animations), firing_dest)
pygame.quit()
```

Alternatively you could manually track the index of the current animation frame, incrementing with each frame and resetting once greater than the length of the list.

EDIT: add destinations as required by [surface.blit()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html?highlight=blit#pygame.Surface.blit)

Comment: it threw up this error:        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/luke.redwine/Documents/Python/PyGame/Space Shooter Game/space rpg.py", line 26, in <module>
    Window.blit(next(neutral_animations))
TypeError: function missing required argument 'dest' (pos 2)

Comment: This is because I'd not provided a destination, I've edited the question to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html?highlight=blit#pygame.Surface.blit

be sure to check the link above, for some documentation, however it may be hard to find answers

**Answer**
Try using blits if you are trying to blit in sequences

for

```
animateNeutral = [pygame.image.load("/Users/luke.redwine/Documents/Python/PyGame/Space Shooter Game/Plasma T Neutral %s.png"% frame)for frame in range (1,3)] 
animateFiring = [pygame.image.load("/Users/luke.redwine/Documents/Python/PyGame/Space Shooter Game/plasma T fire %s.png"% frame)for frame in range (1,7)]
```

This is a list of images, blits() takes a sequence of surfaces (in your case images)
If you are going to use many sprites, you should look into converting the surfaces, if they have transparency (alpha) use convert_alpha()

Comment: blits() is not strictly what the OP is after, they want the animation to iterate every frame.